# Real Clipboard Event using Storybook Interaction Testing?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, storybook

I did some research on how to test real `onPaste` Clipboard event with Jest and React-Testing-Library and realized that it is a challenge:

- [How to paste clipboard data using React Testing Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144715)
- [How to mock onPast event with React and Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492514)
- [How to fire and test a real paste event (not simulated by calling the prop) in Jest and Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877764)

Now that Storybook Interactive Testing runs in a real browser, I am hoping it should be possible.

https://storybook.js.org/blog/interaction-testing-with-storybook/

But my test was unsuccessful.

```
await userEvent.paste(inputEl, 'some text')
```

Not able to access clipboard data from my `handlePaste` function:

```
  const handlePaste = (event: ClipboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const pasted = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
    ...
  }
```

```
TypeError
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getData')
```

Thank you!